# Convert MAC address to Link-local address with bash

Tags: bash, shell, string, ipv6

How can I convert a Mac address into an ipv6 Link-Local address?

you have to add `fe80::` at the start and insert `ff:fe` in the middle

furthermore all leading zeros must be stripped

Comment: You also have to flip the universal/local bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function, that uses `IFS` to split the MAC address into 6 colon-separated groups and assembles them. You'll also need to flip the 7th most significant bit (thanks bahamat), i.e. bit 1 of the first byte:

```
mac_to_ipv6_ll() {
    IFS=':'; set $1; unset IFS
    echo "fe80::$(printf %02x $((0x$1 ^ 2)))$2:${3}ff:fe$4:$5$6"
}
```

Usage example:

```
$ mac_to_ipv6_ll 12:34:56:78:90:12
fe80::1034:56ff:fe78:9012
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `IFS` to split the MAC address into 6 colon-separated groups and assemble them. You'll also need to flip the 7th most significant bit (thanks [bahamat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79349/convert-mac-address-to-link-local-address-with-bash/79352?noredirect=1#comment116902_79352)), i.e. bit 1 of the first byte.

```
mac_to_ipv6 () {
  IFS=':'; set $1; unset IFS
  ipv6_address="fe80::$(printf %02x $((0x$1 ^ 2)))$2:${3}ff:fe$4:$5$6"
}
```

You can use the prefix and suffix stripping constructs [`${VAR#PREFIX}` and `${VAR%SUFFIX}`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to cut the MAC address into pieces.

```
mac_to_ipv6 () {
  mac=$1
  ipv6_address=fe80::$(printf %02x $((0x${mac%%:*} ^ 2)))
  mac=${mac#*:}
  ipv6_address=$ipv6_address${mac%:*:*:*}ff:fe
  mac=${mac#*:*:}
  ipv6_address=$ipv6_address${mac%:*}${mac##*:}
}
```

You can use the substring construct (bash only, not sh).

```
mac_to_ipv6 () {
  local mac=$1 byte0
  printf %02x -v byte0 $((0x${mac:0:2} ^ 2))
  ipv6_address="fe80::$byte0${mac:3:5}ff:fe${mac:9:5}${mac:15:2}"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because link-local addresses have the 7th bit flipped high.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more, I posted a working version below

Answer (score 3):

Taking Gilles' explanation, but correctly [flipping the 7th bit as per IPv6 spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Modified_EUI-64):

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=':'; set $1; unset IFS
printf "fe80::%x%x:%x:%x:%x\n" 0x$(( 0x${1} ^ 0x02 )) 0x${2} 0x${3}ff 0xfe${4} 0x${5}${6}
```

Example of bit-flipping:

```
$ mac_to_ipv6 00:00:00:00:00:00
fe80::200:00ff:fe00:0000
```